# How to query(traverse) along a wide format table?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a table like that.

[image: Table example]

I can't get my head around how to traverse(query selectively) through the countries and output data per date. Sometimes I need one country, sometimes 3 or 5.
I just need to have a separate table where I'll have something like that for later processing (charts and other calculations).
[image]

Usually, I'd use something like

```
=QUERY(A1:100, "SELECT a column WHERE a row ='Name of a country'")
```

or

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(A1:100, "Select * WHERE A = 'Australia'"))
```

But it looks like this logic doesn't work here. Any ideas?

Here is a [dummy sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ofwxEzbIc8RbzQOGTdaovjO-sM29AcwXpAM689dXfDI/edit?usp=sharing)

P.S.
The second Cumulative column it's just an example of calculations that I'll need to do later with each country numbers. I'll just add `=iferror(B3+C2,"0")` Although if you have any better ideas on how to optimise that, I'll be happy to hear it.

Comment: Have you considered doing this with Apps Script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet4!A:AQ), 
 "where Col1 matches 'Date|Australia|India'", 0)), 
 "where Col1 >= "&DATEVALUE("2020-1-23")&" 
    and Col1 <= "&DATEVALUE("2020-1-30"), 1)
```

[image: 0]

and the cumulatives (running totals) can be done like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(O3:O="",,SUMIF(ROW(O3:O), "<="&ROW(O3:O), O3:O)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: further query examples can be found in **j.mp/covid-19spreadsheet/**

Comment: This looks neat. And I think I almost understand it. You did nested queries but I don't understand the ampersands. could you elaborate a little bit? Id like to learn to use this formula myself.

Comment: Cumulative formula wise. I think I know what you did there. IF a cell in column O equals blank, do nothin if true, if false then sum up cells in O column IF its row number is less or equal to the row number.
Is that á correct transcriptions of the formula? I don’t get how the last bit work tho. Could you elaborate.please on that as well.

Comment: And yes I saw your covid19 sheets. amazing. So much to learn. thanks for sharing it.

Comment: cumulative transcriptions: sum range O3:O (third sumif parameter) if row number is equal or smaller (second sumif parameter) than row number of current row (first sumif parameter) an do this only IF O3:O is not empty otherwise output blank cell

Comment: in your dummy sheet there is no United Kingdom but check Sri Lanka: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngDYJ.png

Comment: ampersands... those input dates are not actual dates but numbers visually converted into  dates thats why we dont use **date** parameter inside query string as usually. insted we feed the query with numeric representation of a date eg DATEVALUE so in other words we briefly interupt query string syntax (second parameter of query) to inserdatevalue furmula hence those ampersands

Comment: Gotcha on the ampersands. Thank you

Comment: here's mine: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NsFnxpJjm2Raada1VJ6h1f-wGZr2V9NboMrrVi8i_g8/edit#gid=2049716153

Comment: replied. It's weird but it doesn't work for me in another sheet o_O